# Qt app hangs in release, vcruntime140.dll not found in debug, but my project is using VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, qt, deployment, visual-studio-2015

I had problems with an application I made, it runs perfectly in most of the computers but a couple of them.

I tried to make the simplest Qt project (just a window) and I deployed it using the windeployqt.exe to be sure that I didn't miss something, et voilá, the same problem in the same computers, it hangs forever while loading in Release mode. After that I tried to send him a Debug version and it triggers a vcruntime140.dll not found.

The tricky thing is that I'm using Qt Desktop 5.14.2 MSVC2017 64bit so I cannot imagine why it asks for vcruntime140 (vs2015) also trying to install vs2015 redist manually windows fails since a newer version is already present.

Thank you for any tip, it is driving me nuts!

Comment: `vcruntime140.dll` should not be used in debug so that seems like you have a library conflict where you are mixing debug and release libraries. In debug it should be `vcruntime140d.dll`. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010509/vcruntime140-dll-vs-vcruntime140d-dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010509/vcruntime140-dll-vs-vcruntime140d-dll)

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 through 2019 are binary compatible. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019) you can use the same runtime for all 3. "The latest version of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package (the Redistributable) works for all of them."

Comment: @drescherjm they don't.  vs2019 version of qt uses dll's numbered 140_1. The non-debug version maybe present, by debug version wouldn't be, it's non-redistributable. They aren't presentunless you install MSVC2019 and its SDK. MSVS2017 CAn use  older SDKs and MSVC 2019 can use MSVC2017 SDK, but other way around surrounded by issues "how do I install that?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today Qt 5.15 has been released upgrading my Qt dependencies from 5.14.2 to 5.15 fixed the problem it is not marked as a bugfix in the Qt release but my problems have vanished.

Comment: In my case the issue comes out after a fresh installation of Qt 5.15 (no previous Qt versions on the host). :D

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why build made with MSVC2017 need vcruntime140 to run, but I suggest you to distribute your application via MSI installer. You can create one with WiX toolset ([link](https://wixtoolset.org/)). It may be a little bit hard to start working with this, but you can find a lot of tutorials and information about WiX, over the Internet.

So if you're building an installer, you can attach external resources (Merge Modules [[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_Module)]) which are needed later to run your application. It might be Microsoft Redistributable packages. WiX are using `.wxs` files, which are based on `xml` structure, so for example in one of my installers I have add VC120 and VC140 resources to descriptor of my installer like that:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
    <Merge Id="VC120Redist" SourceFile="Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
    <Merge Id="VC140Redist" SourceFile="Microsoft_VC140_CRT_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
</DirectoryRef>
<Feature Id="VC120Redist" Title="Visual C++ 13 Runtime" AllowAdvertise="no" Display="hidden" Level="1">
    <MergeRef Id="VC120Redist"/>
</Feature>
<Feature Id="VC140Redist" Title="Visual C++ 15 Runtime" AllowAdvertise="no" Display="hidden" Level="1">
    <MergeRef Id="VC140Redist"/>
</Feature>
```

With this approach, installer take care of Microsoft resources, and you don't need to worry if every client pc got proper packages installed.

It's not easy to create good `.wxs` file but in long period it's worth the effort.

Comment: I'm using nsis, but without any luck, notice that even installing vc2015 redist manually didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try to place vcruntime140.dll in your exe directory at problematic OS?

Comment: manual deployment of vc runtimes is a pretty bad practice (I'm not sure about if it is legal neither)

Comment: I know, but just to check that for sure the problem is causing by missing this dll. So you've add proper msm file to your nsis installer?

Comment: The problem with VSRedist and debug was that the missing dll was the Debug version but loads properly on Release.

Still getting freezed in release and Microsoft Procmon didn't showcased any problem

Answer (score 0):

`windeployqt` includes `vc_redist.<arch>` executable in the deployment folder ,  when I deploy an application to other Windows PC , sometimes I get the error claim for `vcruntime140.dll` and other MS Visual C++ redistributable DLLs .. I just run the included executable , like `vc_redist.x64.exe` for 64 bit OS .. and usually problem solved; I understand the point that the target PC might already have a newer version of the redistrib .. but I always thought newer ones are usually backward compatible.. , nevertheless I think Qt includes the right redisreb needed for the application as where it was compiled.